# Typescript how to declare an array of types that can also be empty

Tags: typescript

The function below declares an empty array where the contents can only be of type ElUploadInternalRawFile. The foreach iterates of an array and injects into the said array one object of type ElUploadInternalRawFile at a time.

However,  the compiler now thinks that `const file1` can be either `undefined` or the aforementioned type. But.. as the ItemModule.saveItemImages expects file1 to be ElUploadInternalRawFile it complains and says that it cannot accept file1 as it could be undefined.

I feel like i am in a mad typescript logic loop here.. how can i declare files to be an array of specific types or a plain old empty array..?

```
private async handleImageSubmit(uniqueItemName: string) {
  let files: [ElUploadInternalRawFile?] = [];
  this.getUploadFiles().forEach((file: ElUploadInternalFileDetail) => {
    files.unshift(file.raw)
  });
  if(files.length > 0){
    const file1 = files[0];
    await ItemModule.saveItemImages(uniqueItemName, file1 );
  }
}
```

Here is IDE complaining..
[image]

Comment: You defined a tuple. You are looking for an array `ElUploadInternalRawFile[] `

Comment: :) thanks! Solved it!  https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple